# how to link a css file in laravel 8 layout and disable the base blade css?

Tags: css, laravel, include, web-development-server

in the base.blade.php layout i added this link:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('yes.css')}}">`

but I'm using another layouts with different Css files so how can I include them and disable the base Css?

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('yes.css')}}">
```

It is a correct code. please see your file location. I think your file location is incorrect.